# How to set the Params with id having key and value and pass id dynamically from the server in calling the API

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular8

I am able to call the API ,I have set the params with id having key and values which needs to be pass dynamically as received from the server (ex:s1,s3,s4..these are sensor names received from the server) and I have to pass these sensor names dynamically .

**.service.ts**

```
export class DashboardService {
  public sensors: any[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient, private router: Router) {
  }

  sensorstart(tokenstr) {
    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Token ' + tokenstr
      }),
      params: new HttpParams().set('id', JSON.stringify(this.sensors.map(itm => itm.name)))
    };

    this.http.get(environment.apiUrl + '/api/sensors/start?' + this.id, httpOptions).subscribe(
      (senst: any[]) => {
        // localStorage.setItem("senst",JSON.stringify(senst));
        console.log('senst:', JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('senst')));
        this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);

      },
      err => {
        console.log('Error', err);
      }
    );

  }
}
```

**.component.ts**

```
  this.jammerstart();
--some code--

sensorstart(){
  this.senst=JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("senst"));
console.log("senst",this.senst)
}
```

But in console It is showing

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "sensor started"
}
```

**But I want to show the sensor name in action what I have called dynamically in calling the API.**

I want the below result which changes dynamically in console

```
{
    "status": true,
    "action": "sensor j3 started"
}
```

How can I Pass the id values (sensor names s1,s2,s3--)dynamically in calling the API.

Answer (score 0):

The question seems to be how pass an dynamic array (like s1,s2,s3) to the server.

This is actually depending how the server API has been designed.

If you build the HttpParams like you did:

```
const sensors: any[] = [{name: 's1'},{name: 's2'},{name: 's3'}];    
const httpOptions = {
  params: new HttpParams().set('id', JSON.stringify(sensors.map(itm => itm.name)))
};
this.httpClient.get('api/sensors/start', httpOptions).subscribe();
```

The request url will be something like this:

> /api/sensors/start?id=%5B%22s1%22,%22s2%22,%22s3%22%5D

Which is the encoded string for **["s1","s2","s3"]**

If you want to send it like this

> /api/sensors/start?id=s1&id=s2&id=s3

You may have to do this:

```
const sensors: any[] = [{name: 's1'},{name: 's2'},{name: 's3'}];    
let httpParams = new HttpParams();
for (const sensor of sensors) {
  httpParams = httpParams.append('id', sensor.name);
}
const httpOptions = {
  params: httpParams
};
this.httpClient.get('api/sensors/start', httpOptions ).subscribe();
```

You have to adapt the way you are sending your array depending what the server side is accepting.

The server could also accept another shape:

> /api/sensors/start?id[]=s1&id[]=s2&id[]=s3

or

> /api/sensors/start?id%5B%5D=s1&id%5B%5D=s2&id%5B%5D=s3

or

> /api/sensors/start?id=s1,s2,s3

https://medium.com/raml-api/arrays-in-query-params-33189628fa68

Comment: Thanks, but the array values are not exactly s1,s2,s3 it will be change according to the server.So how can I pass these array values (i.e sensor names changing dynamically)in calling the API.ex :http://{{url}}/api/sensors/start?id=9.